ADF pipeline failure - session terminated due to failure on source side
I am working on a task that involves bulk copying of huge loads of data for six months which is around (2 billion records). I am using copy activity for copying the data from sql server and created sink dataset to point  to azure adls gen 2 storage account to store the data in the form of parquet. I have also set the pipeline timeout for 2 days . But for some reason I keep getting an error message that says pipeline failure happened on ‘Source’ side.
"message": "Failure happened on 'Source' side. 'Type=Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException,Message=111202;Query QID67099467 has been cancelled.\r\nCannot continue the execution because the session is in the kill state.\r\nA severe error occurred on the current command. The results, if any, should be discarded.,Source=Framework Microsoft SqlClient Data Provider,'",
I tried closing all the gaps but still unable to figure out what could have caused the issue at source side.
Below shown code snippet is the json representation of the pipeline I am working on
{
    "name": "CopyPipeline_abc_6months_load",
    "properties": {
        "activities": [
            {
                "name": "ForEach_TableCopy",
                "type": "ForEach",
                "dependsOn": [],
                "userProperties": [],
                "typeProperties": {
                    "items": {
                        "value": "@pipeline().parameters.tableItems",
                        "type": "Expression"
                    },
                    "activities": [
                        {
                            "name": "Copy_to_parquet",
                            "type": "Copy",
                            "dependsOn": [],
                            "policy": {
                                "timeout": "0.20:00:00",
                                "retry": 3,
                                "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
                                "secureOutput": false,
                                "secureInput": false
                            },
                            "userProperties": [],
                            "typeProperties": {
                                "source": {
                                    "type": "SqlServerSource",
                                    "sqlReaderQuery": {
                                        "value": "@concat('select * from ', item().source.table, ' where year([', item().source.dateColumn, '])=2024 and month([', item().source.dateColumn, '])<7 order by month([', item().source.dateColumn, '])')",
                                        "type": "Expression"
                                    },
                                    "partitionOption": "None"
                                },
                                "sink": {
                                    "type": "ParquetSink",
                                    "storeSettings": {
                                        "type": "AzureBlobFSWriteSettings"
                                    },
                                    "formatSettings": {
                                        "type": "ParquetWriteSettings"
                                    }
                                },
                                "enableStaging": false,
                                "validateDataConsistency": true,
                                "translator": {
                                    "type": "TabularTranslator",
                                    "typeConversion": true,
                                    "typeConversionSettings": {
                                        "allowDataTruncation": true,
                                        "treatBooleanAsNumber": false
                                    }
                                }
                            },
                            "inputs": [
                                {
                                    "referenceName": "SourceDataset_b3v",
                                    "type": "DatasetReference",
                                    "parameters": {
                                        "cw_table": "@item().source.table"
                                    }
                                }
                            ],
                            "outputs": [
                                {
                                    "referenceName": "DestinationDataset_b3v",
                                    "type": "DatasetReference",
                                    "parameters": {
                                        "cw_fileName": "@concat(item().destination.filePrefix, '_', formatDateTime(utcnow(), 'yyyyMMddHHmmss'), '.parquet')",
                                        "cw_folder": "@{item().destination.folder}"
                                    }
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        ],
        "parameters": {
            "tableItems": {
                "type": "Array",
                "defaultValue": [
                    {
                        "source": {
                            "table": "abc.123",
                            "dateColumn": "date"
                        },
                        "destination": {
                            "filePrefix": "123",
                            "folder": "123_ingest"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "source": {
                            "table": "abc.345",
                            "dateColumn": "event_date"
                        },
                        "destination": {
                            "filePrefix": "345",
                            "folder": "345_ingest"
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        "folder": {
            "name": "Projects/abc Analytics"
        },
        "annotations": []
    }
}

I even tried extending the pipeline timeout to see if that is causing the issue. But it looks like this issue has nothing to do with session timeout. It seems like the SQL Server might be under heavy load, leading to resource exhaustion and forcing the session to be killed or the server might be encountering internal issues or hitting limits (e.g., memory, CPU).


Message=111202;Query QID67099467 has been cancelled.\r\nCannot continue the execution because the session is in the kill state

To resolve this, you need to make sure you install 2016-SP2 -CU12 update.
You can go through this similar ask by @CWightman about this.
Additionally, your query expression will give syntax error as your table name containing special characters abc.123.
Modify your expression like below.
@concat('select * from [',item().source.table,']')

Wrap your table name expression in [].

